# Android webView - autoplay youtube video from URL

Tags: javascript, android, webview, youtube

Struggling to achieve **Youtube** Video Auto play within android **WebView**, I have seen several threads and forums listing following suggestion which DO NOT WORK.

I have tried the following, with no luck:

1. **settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);**
2. **Adding javascript snip like this:**

   ```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(){
       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           super.onPageFinished(view, url);
           if (view.getProgress() == 100) {
               webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play();"
               );
           }
       }
   });
   ```

3 . **Adding `&autoplay=1` to URL**

I am tested for all the above methods in API 18 and none of the above methods worked. This being a very important Feature for my App, please provide a working solution for this.

Comment: Did you manage to implement a solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Read from this link
[YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/#Getting_Started)

Comment: He is using WebView of Android, probably he's using Iframe Player API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), not the Android Player API